# How many typos in a question is considered too many?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, typographical-error

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74338451/build-aplicaton-on-phisical-divice), which contains a lot of typos ([the original revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/74338451/1)). To some extent, I consider it nearly incomprehensible.

Being afraid of not having enough expertise in the context of the question, my attempts to edit might distort the meaning of the question. I only took the action of downvoting it for now.

How should I handle this kind of question? Should I simply flag it as low quality and downvote it?

Comment: It is a bit extreme. It could be a troll experiment: *"How many misspellings can I* ***deliberately*** *make, and the suckers at Stack Overflow will still put up with it and answer my question?*"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is actually surprisingly common.  People will often type how they speak, and if they don't know the correct spelling of words, they will fill in the gaps with a phonetic equivalent (that makes sense in the way they read it).

Let's be fair to the OP here; they may not be a completely native English speaker.  [Pidgin variations of English exist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English-based_pidgins) which don't conform to exact spelling.  In this circumstance, you should be able to phonetically understand what the OP is trying to say, and you can try to do some editing from there.

If you really *can't* - as in, even after looking at the question and not being sure what's being said, you can't make heads of tails of it - then it'd make sense to downvote it.

I could take a stab at editing it before I go grocery shopping, though...it doesn't seem like it's a particularly *bad* question; someone's trying to get Android Studio to work and they can't get it to connect to their phone.

Comment: Appreciate your answer. Do you have any guideline(s) / threshold(s) for the number of typos in a question that we should attempt to fix? From my understanding of your answer, it should be "fix it if you can; downvote otherwise". Am I understanding it correctly? One of my considerations is that I am not an expert in the particular domain and I cannot distinguish, says `tecno`, is a typo or a specific technical term. Any recommendation for this kind of cases?

Comment: @ray I think being a subject matter expert (SME) also matters. As an Android developer and English as a secondary language speaker, the question is descriptive enough (although possibly misguided since `main()` won't work on the Android app, and possibly not enough detail to reproduce). If you're unsure, you can always do nothing and skip it.

Comment: Meh, there’s absolutely zero excuses for that kind of awful spelling these days, there’s millions of easy to use spell checkers online that anyone can use to correct bad spelling. It’s just laziness (and English isn’t my first language).

Comment: @ray: My recommendation is "yes, if you think the question is useful in spite of its shortcomings."

Comment: @user438383, that's very presumptuous of you. Besides, you can't downvote a question just because it's"lazy", nor can you close a question for that reason, either. If you're not interested in fixing the issue, you can move on to the next question. No need to throw your opinions around of an OP's intrinsic motivation to ask questions.

Comment: You actually can cast that downvote. You shouldn't, but you are very free to do so.

Comment: @Makoto I never even mentioned downvotes, I just take issue with ``Let's be fair to the OP here`` - I don't really have time for people who can't even be bothered to spell check their questions, but that's just my opinion. That said, you could certainly make the case for downvoting, a question like that could absolutely 'not be useful' for non-native speakers who could well have no idea what it's meant to be saying.

Comment: The OP could have gone a long way by not posting from their cell phone.  Software developers use real computers to do their work.

Comment: @RobertHarvey:  You don't know if they were posting *from* their phone.  Even if they were...there's really no harm in that as long as they can be coherent.  Again, I lean more on the fact that they may not be a native English speaker more than the device that they posted from.  On its face, this is a surprising opinion coming from you.  I wouldn't have thought you'd have an assumption like this.

Comment: The unavoidable conclusion is they were using good equipment and still managed to botch their post.  What hope is there for them being successful in programming?  Computers are much more critical about precision than I am.

Answer (score 8):

While [grammar is important](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to an extent that your question can be understood by the community, sloppy typos shouldn't be valued as long as the actual meaning is preserved. The [quality standards](https://stackoverflow.com/help/quality-standards-error) here are defined as:

> Correct use of English spelling and grammar to the best of your
> ability.

If we would start to rate the quality of a question by grammar instead of the programming content, the site would lose the initial purpose. Stack Overflow is a Q&A in plain English, so it can be easily understood all around the globe.

Note, I'm not saying that a question, written so poorly that it's hard or nearly impossible to understand, would be ok. If a question is really not understandable, you can vote to close this question and link them to "[*What’s the best way to ask a question if English isn't your first language?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15308/what-s-the-best-way-to-ask-a-question-if-english-isnt-your-first-language)" or advise them to "*ask someone to proofread it*" as the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) suggests.

---

Ironically, I do expect people to correct my spelling in this answer.

Answer (score 3):

It isn't "typos" that is the problem, it is laziness.

If you type "Waht" by mistake, that's OK, you tried. "wot" on the other hand is simply lazy.

However, every time I see someone criticised online for poor spelling or grammar, they get defensive and mention their learning difficulty and how unkind people are...

So : I find it easiest to simply ignore such questions. Especially if it is hard to understand the question, then you are unlikely to get the right answer.

(NB a lot of non-English native speakers put more effort into being correct than English speakers, or use online translation tools. A lazy native speaker might write "wot u dun", a non-native would be very unlikely to write that.)

Comment: As a non-native speaker, I **always** use a free online spellchecker before I post (not saying that some errors don't slip through though!). There's no excuse for such an excessive amount of bad spelling these days.